# Asynchronous EJB method and rollback

Tags: asynchronous, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

Suppose having an EJB structured like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        doAsynchronously();
        ...
        entityManager.persist(someObject);          
        ...
        if (...) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }   

    public void doAsynchronously() {
        ...
        entityManager.persist(someOtherObject);
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it correct, that when the exception is thrown in the synchronous part and thereby the transaction is rolled back, the asynchronous call is not affected by that and the operations on the entity manager should finish correctly if no error occurs within that method?

I found many examples about asynchronous beans, but not in combination with working on an entity manager in both cases, so if someone can lead me to one, I'll be happy.

---

**EDIT 2013/08/22:**

An additional question - the whole reason for the setup as shown in the code fragment was to be sure that the code in `doAsynchronously()` can completely finish its operations on entities, no matter if an exception occurs in the caller method - so will I get the same behavior if I instead of using `@Asynchronous` annotate with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynchronous method is executed in another thread, and will thus not execute in the context of the current transaction, and will use another persistence context as well.

If the goal is to start a new transaction, unaffected by the errors you might have in the current one, REQUIRES_NEW is indeed the solution. But simply using REQUIRES_NEW won't make the call asynchronous: it will block the current transaction untile the new one is ficished, and the current transaction will then resume.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I know that the 2nd solution is synchronous, but as I said, the intention was to finish certain entity operations, even if others are rolled back due to an exception, not that it runs necessarily asynchronously.